# AWS - Custom token expiration time

Tags: amazon-web-services, token, refresh, amazon-cognito

I'm working on some sensitive web application, and I would like to disconnect users after 5mn of inactivity.

I'm stuck with the 1 day minimum refresh token timeout (set on cognito management console)...
How can I bypass this ? Or set the refresh token timeout  < 1 day ?

I'm using the aws-amplify module

I've seen a lot of similar questions and it seems there is no way to do it properly...
Thanks in advance

Comment: How about calling signOut on a timer to revoke the tokens?

Comment: that's a solution, but won't work when the browser is closed...

Comment: You could always save the timestamp when it was generated locally and check next time time user opens the page again if certain time has passed and trigger sign out then. You are using a library to manage cognito so unfortunately your options are limited.

Comment: I did something like that and it works thanks for your advice
Still, i find it weird that aws-amplify doesn't provide such a basic functionality

Comment: If they have a forum where the developers interact with users you can try making feature request there